# How to write a Windows filename with åäö in command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, character-set

I need to write a command line in the command prompt that references a file containing åäö in its name, but I can't seem to get it right. Windows should be set to codepage win1252 and the command prompt to oem850.

The specific filename is:

```
Förändringar.txt
```

I was able to use `dir /x` to get the short 8.3 filename and use that, but it bugs me to be unable to get the long name right...

**Update:**

The comments have led me to conclude that it's not a problem with the command prompt (`cmd.exe` to clarify). It seems to be a problem with the particular console application I was trying to run (`gfix.exe` from the Firebird database manager). Apparently it fails to correctly convert command line arguments from the console codepage to whatever it needs to use internally.

Comment: What version of Windows are you on, and which command line interface (command.com (hopefully not), cmd.exe, powershell, anything third-party?) are you using? I have never had anything like the problem you are describing, which leads me to believe that you are doing something unusual. Please **[edit]** your question to clarify.

Comment: äöüÄÖÜ work fine here with cmd.exe, dir and ren, so what exactly does not work as expected?

Comment: Aha, sorry. I think it's not a command prompt (cmd.exe) problem, but a problem with the actual console application I was trying to invoke. It seems it fails to convert the filename from the command line args correctly from the console codepage. I guess I'll have to check with the app developers. (It's the Firebird database manager's gfix utility.)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show a code snippet satisfying [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) rules and specify whether you do run `gfix.exe` from pure `cmd` or from a batch script. Use `chcp 1257` or `chcp 1254` prior to running `gfix.exe` from an open `cmd` window. Simply: use `chcp` to a code page where all `åäö` characters are defined.

Answer (score -1):

The normal command prompt in Windows is CMD.EXE. This is a Unicode program. In Unicode, there's no need for things like "Win1252" and "OEM850".

I suspect that you're using *batch files*, as those can be non-Unicode. CMD.EXE will understand batch files that are in non-Unicode, but avoid them when using non-ASCII characters. Just use Unicode batch files.

Comment: Unfortunately, if not cmd.exe then at least the Windows console itself still uses codepages to this day, and while programs _can_ output Unicode, they must go out of their way to do so. (I have dealt with this for a decade and just re-tested on a fresh Server 2012 R2 system to make sure.) The CMD built-in `dir` command only shows question marks for characters outside the current OEM codepage (as shown by `chcp`), and the console itself doesn't let me input them (e.g. pressing `ąčęė` causes `acee` to appear if the codepage is not 775). PowerShell doesn't get this right either.

Comment: @grawity: I don't think it does. The question marks are not a result of code pages, that's the result of using a font which doesn't have the characters. Programs don't need to do something special for the console, `WriteConsole` maps to `WriteConsoleW` (wide) for Unicode programs. Just like `MessageBox`->`MessageBoxW`.

Comment: Hmm, looks like you're right about the font. I can't believe I forgot that _again_. I keep rediscovering this every few months...